# How to sort a list of strings that contain a combination of letters and numbers

Tags: sort, delete, duplicate

I want to sort following strings by the number and remove duplication in a file

```
cat311
celine434
celine434
celine5
jimmy12
john44
john41
```

to be

```
celine5
jimmy12
john41
john44
cat311
celine434
```

Answer (score 1):

You could insert a `,` (or any character which otherwise doesn't occur in the input) before the first digit, and then sort on the part after that `,`:

```
$ <file sed 's/[0123456789]/,&/' | sort -ut, -k2n -k1,1 | tr -d ,
celine5
jimmy12
john41
john44
cat311
celine434
```

Comment: This is awesome! I need to learn more about sed! Thank you!

Comment: What does "-k1,1" do here? I find following also give the same output.

<file sed 's/[0123456789]/,&/' | sort -ut, -k2n  | tr -d ,

Comment: @user8090410, it adds the first field (the username) as the secondary sorting key. Try on the output of `printf  '%s\n' john1 joe1` for instance to see the difference.